# What is the name of the default date format used by MySQL?

Tags: mysql

MySQL defaults to displaying columns of type [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) using the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Does this format have a name, such as the RFC 1123 format? How pervasive is this format among database vendors?

An example of a date value displayed in this format would be:
`2013-05-13 12:58:26`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's commonly known as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: ISO 8601 _requires_ a `T` separating date & time, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Wrikken Seems so that it can be omited by mutual agreement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#cite_note-13

Comment: Damn, you're right, missed that first time around, sorry. As you were ;)